# Can I set incoming calls to silent/vibrate, but still get an audible notification for texts?

Tags: notifications

Can I set incoming calls to silent/vibrate, but still get an audible notification for texts?

I'd like to be able to set my phone to silent for incoming calls, but still be able to hear incoming texts and other alerts. Is this possible?

Currently (still :( )running Android 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Settings-> Sounds -> Phone ringtone -> None

Settings->Sounds-> Default Notification  Sound -> Any ringtone

Check vibrate on ring

or you can go to the messaging app and set the ringtone from the menu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, by either going to your sound settings setting each tone individually (i.e., ringtone, notification tone, and media tone) or on your home screen just press your volume rocker and from there also you can set the volume differently for all the three.